# Why is user_score and computer_score not being added to? (i think)

Tags: python, blackjack

So I'm, coding a blackJack game,and I made a list called user_score and computer_score. I used the random module to choose a random int from a list called cards. But when I use .append() to add the random choice from cards, it doesn't appear to be adding the random card to user_card / computer_card? Here is where I define it, and where I use the random module:

```
import random

user_score = 0
computer_score = 0

cards = [11, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10]

user_cards = []
computer_cards = []



def deal_card():
cards_left = 2
while not cards_left == 0:
    random_user = random.choice(cards)
    random_computer = random.choice(cards)
    user_cards.append(random_user)
    computer_cards.append(random_computer)
    cards_left -= 1
    print(user_score, computer_score)
```

and finally, this is where I call the function:

```
deal_card()
calculate_score(card_list=[user_score, computer_score])
```

calculate_score is defined here:

```
def calculate_score(card_list):
user_score = sum(user_cards)
computer_score = sum(computer_cards)

if computer_cards.count(11) > 0 and computer_cards.count(10) > 0:
    computer_score = 0
elif user_cards.count(11) > 0 and user_cards.count(10) > 0:
    user_score = 0  
if user_cards.count(11) > 0:
    cards.remove(11)
    cards.append(1)
elif computer_cards.count(11) > 0:
    cards.remove(11)
    cards.append(1)
return user_score
```

PS: I'm still learning python, so please don't go *to* advanced

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that the variables `user_cards` and `computer_cards` are not in the scope of `deal_card()` or `calculate_score()`. As mentioned in the previous answers, one way to deal with this problem is by using `global` variables. Another way to solve this, would be by `passing` and `returning` **variables** in your functions:

```
import random

# Pass cards variable to function
def deal_card(cards):
    cards_left = 2
    user_cards = []
    computer_cards = []
    while not cards_left == 0:
        random_user = random.choice(cards)
        random_computer = random.choice(cards)
        user_cards.append(random_user)
        computer_cards.append(random_computer)
        cards_left -= 1
        print(user_score, computer_score)
    # return user_cards and computer_cards array
    return user_cards, computer_cards

# Pass user_cards and computer_cards array to function
def calculate_score(user_cards, computer_cards):
    user_score = sum(user_cards)
    computer_score = sum(computer_cards)

    if computer_cards.count(11) > 0 and computer_cards.count(10) > 0:
        computer_score = 0
    elif user_cards.count(11) > 0 and user_cards.count(10) > 0:
        user_score = 0
    if user_cards.count(11) > 0:
        cards.remove(11)
        cards.append(1)
    elif computer_cards.count(11) > 0:
        cards.remove(11)
        cards.append(1)
    # return user_score and computer_score
    return user_score, computer_score

cards = [11, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10]

# call deal_card with cards array
user_cards, computer_cards = deal_card(cards)

# call calculate_score with user_cards and computer_cards returned from deal_cards
user_score, computer_score = calculate_score(user_cards, computer_cards)
```

Answer (score 2):

In Python, any variable that you set in a function is a separate local variable in that function. To access the global variable instead, you have to write a `global` statement like this:

```
def calculate_score(card_list):
    global user_score, computer_score
    user_score = sum(user_cards)
    computer_score = sum(computer_cards)
    ...
```

If you don't set a variable but only read it, it uses the global one, which is why you can access `user_cards` and `computer_cards` inside the function. `cards.remove` does not actually change the `cards` variable but just reads it to see which list to edit, and then edits that list, which is why it accesses the global `cards`.

Comment: when I run this: print(user_score, computer_score) it still prints 0.0 for both

Comment: @SmallComputer12 seems like your program prints the score and **then** calculates it? because printing the score is part of deal_card and deal_card is called before calculate_score?

Answer (score 2):

You are not updating the global variables `user_score` and `computer_score`. To fix this issue, you need to declare these variables as `global` within the `calculate_score` function. Following is the updated `calculate_score` function:

```
def calculate_score():
    global user_score
    global computer_score
    user_score = sum(user_cards)
    computer_score = sum(computer_cards)

    if computer_cards.count(11) > 0 and computer_cards.count(10) > 0:
        computer_score = 0
    elif user_cards.count(11) > 0 and user_cards.count(10) > 0:
        user_score = 0  
    if user_cards.count(11) > 0:
        cards.remove(11)
        cards.append(1)
    elif computer_cards.count(11) > 0:
        cards.remove(11)
        cards.append(1)
```

Also, call the function without passing any arguments. Since you are using the global variables I don't think you need to pass any arguments to `calculate_score` function.

```
deal_card()
calculate_score()
```

Comment: I did that, but after I removed the arguments, it gave me this error:                        Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 43, in <module>
    calculate_score()
TypeError: calculate_score() missing 1 required positional argument: 'card_list'

Comment: You didn't update the `calculate_score` function signature

Comment: that too, also, i just realized i was printing the wrong thing. LOL

Comment: Did it work for you?

Comment: user_cards and computer_cards seem to be print as two different lists. is that normal?

Comment: Yes. Those are after all two different lists.